# After uncheck the checkbox value is not inserted in mvc application

Tags: arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, enums

I have one checkbox and one textbox, now when I check the checkbox and write text in textbox at that time checkbox value and textbox value is inserted, but when I am uncheck the checkbox and write the text in textbox at that time textbox value is not inserted in database.

Here is my code

I used enum value for checkbox and textbox

Here is the enum code

```
public enum ChassisJobTypeEnum
{
    LinerChange = 1,
    ChainSetChange = 2  
}
```

Here is the view design code

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Change Linear</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-group" id="ChassisJob@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.LinerChange)_Checked" placeholder="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-group" id="ChassisJob.@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.LinerChange)_OtherJob" placeholder="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Change Chain Set</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-group" id="ChassisJob@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.ChainSetChange)_Checked" placeholder="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-group" id="ChassisJob.@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.ChainSetChange)_OtherJob" placeholder="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when submit the form at that time ajax is calling to the controller

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();

 var chassisJobs = [];
 chassisJob = {
     ChassisJobsTypeId: @((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.LinerChange),                                 
     Checked: $("#ChassisJob@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.LinerChange)_Checked").prop('checked'),
     OtherJob: document.getElementById("ChassisJob.@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.LinerChange)_OtherJob").value,                                 
 };
 chassisJobs.push(chassisJob);

 chassisJob = {
    ChassisJobsTypeId: @((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.ChainSetChange),
    Checked: $("#ChassisJob@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.ChainSetChange)_Checked").prop('checked'),
    OtherJob: document.getElementById("ChassisJob.@((int)ChassisJobTypeEnum.ChainSetChange)_OtherJob").value,
 };
 chassisJobs.push(chassisJob);

var serviceJobData = {
    'Id': document.getElementById("Id").value,                            
    'ChassisJob': chassisJobs
    };

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/ServiceJob/AddUpdate',
         data: serviceJobData,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             if (data.success == true) {
                   alert("Data has been update successfully");

                 //RefreshTable();
                 location.reload(true);

      // set focus on edit form
      document.getElementById("service-job-list").scrollIntoView();

      //reste form
      var frm = document.getElementsByName('service-job-form')[0];
      frm.reset();

  }
  else {
        alert("Unable to insert data")
     }
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert('Failed to add Detail.');
        }
   });
});
```

Here is the controller in which the addupdate method is calling at submit button.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddUpdate(ServiceJobModel model)
{
    ServiceJob serviceJob = new ServiceJob();
    bool iSInsertData = true;

    var chassisJobs = _Db.ChassisJob.Where(x => x.ServiceJobId == model.Id).ToList();
    if (chassisJobs.Any())
    {
        _Db.ChassisJob.RemoveRange(chassisJobs);
        _Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });            
}
```

Now, this is code which I tried.

For more clear, let see task image.

When I check the checkbox and enter the value in textbox at that time insert data properly and at the fetch time it shows the checkbox and textbox value properly.

[image]

now, when I uncheck the checkbox and enter the value in textbox at that time data is not inserted and at the fetch time it does not show any thing.

[image]

If you any issue to understand the question then feel free to ask.

Comment: In the AddUpdate method from the controller do you also have insert code, right now it only shows the remove code for duplicate serviceJob.. In there if you could set a breakpoint and step through and look for errors with logic.. Also please check for JavaScipt errors, and for call back errors with Fiddler..

Comment: Why are you using ajax when you then just doing `location.reload();` - you may as well just make a normal submit and redirect. And if you generate you view correctly by binding to a model, then your code can be reduces by about 50%